# Проблема с шаблоном for в django с разными html документами

Tags: python, html, css, django

У меня не хочет выводиться товар на другой странице, на главной он выводиться как надо, а на другой не хочет ( код вывода в html одинаковых на обеих страницах)

Код вывода в html шаблоне:

```
        {% for product_image in products_images %}
        <div class="flex_card">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-img"><img class="img-responsive" src="{{ product_image.image.url }}"></div>
            <div class="card-info">
                <p class="text-title">{{ product_image.product.name }}</p>
                <p class="text-body">{{ product_image.product.description|truncatechars_html:60 }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <span class="text-title">{{ product_image.product.price }}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="btn_card">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Добавить в корзину</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

скрин главной странице (товар выводиться):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин другой страницы (товар не выводится и карточки вообще не показываются, css правильный)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дополните, пожалуйста, скрином domtree

Comment: Начать стоит с логичного вопроса - на этой самой "другой странице" переменная products_images вообще существует?

Comment: andreymal

Код views.py (запрос как с главной страницы, так и с другой):

https://imgur.com/a/ZT09ceh